# Flutter webview force the dark mode Solution?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an application in Flutter (with a webview) and when dark mode is activated on the device, the webview changes the colors of the web (text and background) to make it dark  , creating a horrible result.
I have tried to set the entire app in light mode (themeMode: ThemeMode.light) but it doesn’t work.
i also set colour is white in my website its looks normal in Chrome. Do you know how it could be solved?
Thank you?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the application after doing the changes?

Comment: Ashok i do this many time but not work

Comment: have u found an answer for this?

Comment: No John Still panding

Answer (score 0):

Add the below dependency to your `gradle` build:

`implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.3.0'`

And add the below code snippet to your `webview initialization`:

```
if(WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(myWebView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON);
}
```

[Can check the Credits here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449900/letting-webview-on-android-work-with-prefers-color-scheme-dark)

Comment: I already set this for all app but it does not work

Comment: after changes did you try to restart?

Comment: Thank you Ashok for your efforts can you please clear this where I can use this snippet in my code. I try to use but not understand how I can use snippet.