# WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK) returns false

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I'm trying to add a dark theme to my app (which uses an Android web view) but whenever I call to check `WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)` to see if my web view supports it, it returns false. I'm running on a simulator with API version 29, and my app has a target version of 29 with a min version of 16. How can I make sure this method returns true?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the accepted answer of [Letting WebView on Android work with prefers-color-scheme: dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449900/letting-webview-on-android-work-with-prefers-color-scheme-dark)

> The isFeatureSupported check is to make sure the Android System
> WebView version the user has installed on their device supports dark
> mode (since this can be updated or downgraded independently from the
> Android version through Google Play)

**So in my case, after I updated Android System Webview on the device/emulator, the issue was resolved.** If you have problem to update the app (for example, update pending problem), please check whether the app has auto-update enabled. [Check auto-update of app in Google Playstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Eki.png). For more possible solutions to update problems, please refer to this article: [Fix: Chrome and Android System Webview is not getting updated](https://browserhow.com/fix-chrome-and-android-system-webview-is-not-getting-updated/#:%7E:text=Relaunch%20the%20Google%20Play%20Store,Google%20Play%20services%20as%20well.)

My running environment:

- minSdk 23
- targetSdk 31
- Pixel 3 API 29

Hope it helps!